# Relating tables with repositories and services pattern (laravel)

Tags: php, laravel

I have a question about the pattern... When it comes to creating some entity relationships in a single request. Breaks the pattern if I just put like:
`this->model->relationship->create()`...
Or is it better to go back to the service and then send it to the other repository, for example:
`(new ExampleService)->create($data);`.
Or is there another way to do this without breaking the pattern?

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow raissadev. please take a [tour] and learn [ask]. fyi, laravel has service container and dependency injection - utilize those.

Comment: It seems clearly that the relation should be defined into the model(infrastructure), but the adequate layer to access that relation would be the repository(application). So from your  ExampleService(domain) you will have access to  relation from repository trough dependency injection. ¿is this correct?

Comment: Exactly! But one of the problems is accessing the pivot tables from them... Making this process of returning to services ends up making the code very long (even abstracting a lot), in addition to the problem of setting the pivot tables... I wanted a solution that could improve it...

Comment: But I'll see about how to use dependency injection to solve this.
Thanks so much for your tip!

Comment: Apparently that didn't solve my problem... But to explain it better, I'm just having doubts about managing relationships, adhering to the repository standard. What to do when I want to create children in this repository, do I need to access this child's services or directly access its repository?